# Accessing a List property of an object

Tags: c#, list

I have a simple Class that I thought I could make more useful if I added a list property to store some values ( i dont want an array bc I dont know how long it will be)

```
public class MyClass
{
public double myProperty1;
public double myProperty2;
//etc
public  List<double> myList {get; set;}


}
```

but when I try to access this property, for example by

```
if x >y

newObject.myList.Add(x);
```

I get an error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyClass
{

    public double myProperty1;
    public double myProperty2;
    //etc
    public  List<double> myList {get; private set;}  // private set

    public MyClass()    // constructor
    {
           myList = new List<double>();    // create the list
    }
}
```

Your class instances need an actual `List<>` instance. The right place to create it is in a constructor. The private setter is usually a good idea but not essential.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. I thought I would need to initialize the list but I just wasnt sure where.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the list. It is declared only, not initialized automatically.

Initialize it in the constructor:

```
public MyClass()
{
    MyList = new List<double>();
}
```

(BTW, to be compliant with naming conventions, properties must be Pascal-cased, not Camel-cased... So `myList` should be `MyList`.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the list to something - it is not initialized, hence it is `null`.

In the class constructor, you could do:

```
public MyClass()
{
  myList = new List<double>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize the list first to work properly, than add item like as below

```
if ( newObject.myList==null)
    newObject.myList= new List<double>();
newObject.myList.Add(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of the list. You can add initialization to the constructor of class:

```
public class MyClass
{
public double myProperty1;
public double myProperty2;
//etc
public  List<double> myList {get; set;}

public MyClass(){
   myList = new List<double>();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use implicit properties with object like a List if you don't create an instance by yourself.

```
// Implicit declaration, a field is created in background, but the object isn't initialized.
public  List<double> myList {get; set;}
```

Instead:

```
// Explicit declaration, with me creating an instance
private List<double> myList = new List<double>();

public List<double> MyList
{
    get { return myList; }    
}
```

Another way would be to initialize your implicit declaration in your constructor. But I like to write my own field.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy need to initialize myList before you use could be in constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{

public MyClass()
{
    myList  = new List<double>();
}

public double myProperty1;
public double myProperty2;
//etc
public  List<double> myList {get; set;}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must instantiate the `List<double>` object as a new object. Without the istantiation it's only a pointer.